# Alfresco Community Edition "Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server"

Tags: tomcat, alfresco

After installing the Alfresco WAR's I'm getting the error message in the browser after startup: "Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server. (Does this application have access to alfresco-global.properties? Does this application have cross-context permissions?)"

In the Tomcat logs I'm seeing the following:

```
22-Jun-2019 04:23:39.370 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/alfresco.xml]
22-Jun-2019 04:23:39.425 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/alfresco]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1833)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@527e7b4b]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4885)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5020)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet@6d126415]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:691)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The directory specified by base and internal path [/opt/tomcat/../modules/platform]/[] does not exist.
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.checkType(DirResourceSet.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractFileResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractFileResourceSet.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.initInternal(DirResourceSet.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 16 more
22-Jun-2019 04:23:39.426 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying configuration descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/alfresco.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/alfresco]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1833)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
22-Jun-2019 04:23:39.427 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/alfresco.xml] has finished in [56] ms
22-Jun-2019 04:23:39.427 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/share.xml]
22-Jun-2019 04:23:39.431 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/share]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1833)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@429a9b88]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4885)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5020)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet@2d21e20d]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:691)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The directory specified by base and internal path [/opt/tomcat/../modules/share]/[] does not exist.
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.checkType(DirResourceSet.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractFileResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractFileResourceSet.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.initInternal(DirResourceSet.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 16 more
22-Jun-2019 04:23:39.432 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying configuration descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/share.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/share]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1833)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Key error line looks to be `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The directory specified by base and internal path [/opt/tomcat/../modules/platform]/[] does not exist.` - what directories did you set in your global properties?

Comment: @Gagravarr Directories for what, specifically? I followed the guide in the docs and set all the things it mentioned

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using, and what docs did you follow?

Comment: @Gagravarr the version is “Alfresco Community Edition 201901 GA” and I’m following the docs at https://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/install-community-intro.html

Comment: Did you install Tomcat manually? If so, did you configure the Tomcat shared class loader?

Comment: @JeffPotts I did install Tomcat manually, but I did nothing with the shared class loader... can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are installing Tomcat manually you must set up a shared classloader. This is not done by default when you install Tomcat. The Alfresco docs cover it [here](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/configfiles-change-path.html).

This is critical because the shared/classes folder is where the alfresco-global.properties file resides as well as the alfresco/extension and alfresco/web-extension folders. These latter directories need to be populated with files from the zip distribution archive as explained in the docs.

Comment: This was the whole issue. Thanks for pointing me to that Alfresco doc, I must've missed it!

Answer (score 0):

"Does this application have access to alfresco-global.properties? Does this application have cross-context permissions"

Please check if  alfresco-global.properties is present at 
< alfresco-home >/tomcat/shared/classes